reverse order by group in polars
I'd like to reverse (not sort!) the order of a column in a polars dataframe, but only for the scope of a group. I know this is not so common, but I stumbled over a use case, where I need a symmetric group by operation for both ordereings (normal and reversed).
Here is some example code:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    data={
        'group': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
        'value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    }
)

print(df)

shape: (5, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ value │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ a     ┆ 1     │
│ a     ┆ 2     │
│ a     ┆ 3     │
│ b     ┆ 4     │
│ b     ┆ 5     │
└───────┴───────┘

And my expected result would be:
shape: (5, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ value │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ a     ┆ 3     │
│ a     ┆ 2     │
│ a     ┆ 1     │
│ b     ┆ 5     │
│ b     ┆ 4     │
└───────┴───────┘

Is there also a way to do such an operation withing a .with_columns() call?

You can use .over()
df.with_columns(pl.col("value").reverse().over("group"))

shape: (5, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ value │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ a     ┆ 3     │
│ a     ┆ 2     │
│ a     ┆ 1     │
│ b     ┆ 5     │
│ b     ┆ 4     │
└───────┴───────┘

See Window Functions in the user guide:

https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/expressions/window/


Disregarding the .with_columns() call, it is actually pretty easy (like so many things in polars):
df.group_by('group').map_groups(lambda grp: grp.reverse())


If you are not doing any aggregation of the groups, you can use the .sort method of the data frame and pass a list to the descending argument.
df.sort('group', 'value', descending=[False, True])

returns:
shape: (5, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ group ┆ value │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str   ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ a     ┆ 1     │
│ a     ┆ 2     │
│ a     ┆ 3     │
│ b     ┆ 4     │
│ b     ┆ 5     │
└───────┴───────┘

